# How to sort arbitary multidimensional vector using sort()?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

for example, I have 5 int vector:

```
a:3,5,9
b:3,5
c:
d:3,5,2
e:2,17
```

I want the sort result is : c,e,b,d,a, because:

c is shortest, so at first

first element of e is minimum, so it is at second

b and d has same element at first and second, but b has shorter size, so as third

the third element of a is larger than d, so a is the last

the vector as code:

```
std::vector<int> a;
a.push_back(3);
a.push_back(5);
a.push_back(9);

std::vector<int> b;
b.push_back(3);
b.push_back(5);

std::vector<int> c;

std::vector<int> d;
d.push_back(3);
d.push_back(5);
d.push_back(2);

std::vector<int> e;
e.push_back(2);
e.push_back(17);

std::vector<std::vector<int> >myvector;
myvector.push_back(a);
myvector.push_back(b);
myvector.push_back(c);
myvector.push_back(d);
myvector.push_back(e);
```

the vector is in the vector "myvector", how to write a sort() function to handle "myvector" which will get my expected sort result?

Answer (score 1):

use `srand`?

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

then

```
sort(myvector.begin(), myvector.end());
```

Comment: No need for `srand`, just `std::sort(myvector.begin(), myvector.end());` is fine, as `std::sort` uses [`operator<` for `std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp), which compares in lexicographical order. You don't need any shuffling or random number generators here.

Comment: the question said arbitrary sort for a vector not really sure what he's asking then, I figured  random generated numbers being sorted.in a vector. thanks tho

Comment: I think OP just meant that any possible combination of such vectors should be sortable. Basically wants to sort any `vector<vector<int>>`, and `std::sort` is doing exactly what OP wants.